# How to get the values of column fields in Outlook with office.js?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-2016

In Outlook, users can add built-in (email size, importance, etc.) or custom columns that will appear in their inbox view. (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-or-remove-columns-in-the-inbox-78098e3e-8203-47da-815e-cb66f76b512e)

How can I read their values? For example, how can I get the email size? Or how can get the value of a custom column?

I've read the whole [documentation reference of Outlook Javascript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook?view=outlook-js-preview), but I couldn't find anything.

**Categories and CustomProperties are not what I am looking for.**

I hope somebody can help me ‍♂️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These properties are not directly available through add-in APIs. You can use the [makeEwsRequestAsync API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/web-services) to make a call to the Exchange backend, and use the [GetItem EWS Operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/getitem-operation-email-message) to get properties of the message. Modify the [ItemShape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/itemshape) element to specify the properties you need.

Note that your add-in must specify the [ReadWriteMailbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/understanding-outlook-add-in-permissions#readwritemailbox-permission) permission in its add-in manifest.

Answer (score 1):

I used the `ews-javascript-api` library. (There is `ews-js-api-browser` for use in browser)

This allows to load the info related to the item pretty easy.

```
const loadedItem = await exch.BindToItems(
      [new ewsjs.ItemId(Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId)],
      new ewsjs.PropertySet(
        ewsjs.BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties,
        ewsjs.EmailMessageSchema.Size,
      ),
    )
```

If you do not wanna use the library you have to write EWS requests yourself as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/explore-the-ews-managed-api-ews-and-web-services-in-exchange) in the docs.